# Renew domain for 10 years on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

So I'm working on transferring my domain to AWS Route53, and I'm wondering. I currently have the domain renewed for ten years. Will that remain? also, can I renew for that long on AWS?

**Update:** Hmmmmm:

> Generic TLDs
>
> When you transfer a domain that has a generic TLD (for example, .com)
>   to Amazon Route 53, the new expiration date for the domain is the
>   expiration date with your previous registrar plus one year.

From: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53-expiration.html

Seems that if my domain was renewed for ten years with my old registrar, that transferring to AWS Route53 would extend it to eleven years. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route 53 Renewals are per year so you cannot renew for 10 Years. For keeping the current renewal period check this table.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53-expiration.html

Yes it will renew it for 11 years.

Comment: That's a shame. It's a factor in SEO.

Comment: @Costa if that's an issue for you, then keep your old registrar and just use Route53 DNS servers. There is no requirement to move the domain registration to AWS in order to use Route53.

Comment: True. And, I know it's knit picky, and not a major SEO factor, so I might just bite the bullet. Thanks!!!